# Country Code Picker issue: Library not found

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to build an app in which I am implementing authentication using a "contact number" and therefore it requires use of 'country-code-picker' library. Even after declaring the country code picker library in my module(build.gradle) file, still I am getting this error while using it in my XML file.

`Class referenced in the layout file, com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker, was not found in the project or the libraries`

XML file

```html
<com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
            android:id="@+id/ccp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:ccp_autoDetectCountry="true"
            app:ccp_showNameCode="false"
            tools:ccp_contentColor="#fcfdfd"
            tools:ccp_textSize="20dp" />
```

build.gradle file

```html
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.whatsappclone"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:X.Y.Z'
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put in your dependencies like this -> implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.5.0'

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter the valid version in the dependency you pasted, `implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:X.Y.Z'`
The version number is not `X.Y.Z`, it is `2.4.2`.
So try this `implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.2'` and sync your gradle file.
Let me know if it works.
You can refer this https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject#how-to-add-to-your-project

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget this
add project gradle

```
 repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the dependencies in proper format.

In the gradle file you have used implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:X.Y.Z' here X,Y,Z refers to the library versions.

So put the latest version or any version that is supported.